# flatpickr.js works in development but not in production using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, production, flatpickr

I have a schedule with flatpickr in production mode, it gives the following error:

```
appointmentForm.js: 1 ReferenceError: Cannot access 't' before initialization
```

```
const flatpickr = require("flatpickr").default;
const esp = require("flatpickr/dist/l10n/es.js").default.es;

flatpickr.localize(esp);

flatpickr("#dob", {
    dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
    minDate: new Date().fp_incr(-365 * 100),
    maxDate: "today",
});
```

Comment: Build your project locally and make sure verbose logging is enabled and share the whole trace. I don't see anything here that would cause this problem.

Comment: You would have to post more code, "appointmentForm.js" and "t" are not in the code you have right now.